# Can't get events to work on images with Highmaps

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I'm trying to get the `click` and `mouseOver` handlers to work with Highmaps. I've checked the docs and tried to follow their examples. I inserted the event handler configs just about everywhere where I think it makes sense.

The wanted result is that the `click` and `mouseOver` handlers get called when hovering and clicking on the labels (pin icons) in the map.

Fiddle with my non-working code:
http://jsfiddle.net/fyp86hct/1/

One of the Highmaps examples shows that you should be able to do this:

```
point:
{
    events:
    {
        click: function ()
        {
            alert("this doesn't work"); // <--  non working event handler
        },
        mouseOver: function()
        {
            alert("this doesn't work"); // <--  non working event handler
        }
    }                                
}
```

Comment: For me it works, see: http://jsfiddle.net/fyp86hct/2/ - just your dataLabels are overlapping shapes, so it's hard to mouseOver/click on the element.

Comment: I'm sorry, I realize my question wasn't clear enough. It's the shapes (pin icons) that should detect the hover/click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not supported, but you can add shape by [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer) and then attach click event.